# Languages with strict or less strict grammar

Tags: grammar

I speak German and Dutch and it seems to me that the German grammar more "enforcing" or "strong" is. I explain my impression :

German grammar rules are non ambiguous. I think for instance of the words order : there is one right way, and other ways are wrong. In a relative proposition, the verb is non ambiguously in the last position, in case there is a modal verb with double infinitive the rule is also strict and unambiguous.

In Dutch, there is also a rule, that verbs are in the last position in a relative proposition, however, for instance

> De journalist betreurt het dat de beloften van het regeerakkoord niet **nagekomen worden**.

and

> De journalist betreurt het dat de beloften van het regeerakkoord niet **worden nagekomen**.

seems to be both correct. There might be more natural word order, but there are several acceptable ways.

Do some languages have a strict grammar and others a less strict grammar? Is it a field of study and how to qualify how much a language abide by its grammar?

Comment: the two quoted Dutch sentences are identical. Was the bottom one meant to read "worden nagekomen"?

Comment: This is, in general, not about the language or its grammar, but about the social significance accorded to particular varieties of the language. In all languages there is variation - geographical, social, age-related, and in various other ways. In modern nations there is generally a variety (or several) with particularly high prestige, and - often for reasons of nationalism - people have for generations been taught the bare-faced pernicious lie that there is something wrong with the way they speak their own language, that it is "wrong" or "bad grammar", or other fictions for social control.